# Busca por NULL mysql via Java

Tags: java, mysql, sql

Pretendo gravar um residto no meu banco de dados via java quando um dos parâmetros buscados for `NULL`, mas acontece que não encontro a forma de passar esse comando.

Meu código é:

```
public Usuario registraSaida(String nome) throws SQLException {
    String sql = "UPDATE usuario_acesso SET data_saida = ? WHERE usuario_nome = ? AND data_saida = NULL";
    java.sql.Timestamp date = new java.sql.Timestamp(new java.util.Date().getTime());

    PreparedStatement pst = conexao.prepareStatement(sql);
    pst.setTimestamp(1, date);
    pst.setString(2, nome);
    pst.executeUpdate();

    System.out.println(nome);
    return null;
}
```

Comment: No SQL, toda comparação com `NULL` vai retornar falso. No caso, você precisa  verificar se a data é nula: `data_saida IS NULL`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Altere o preenchimento da `String sql` para

```
String sql = "UPDATE usuario_acesso SET data_saida = ? WHERE usuario_nome = ? AND data_saida IS NULL";
```

Como falado em comentário, a "comparação" deve ser feita com ***[IS NULL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/is-null-optimization.html)***.